Attempting to Parallelize Google Vertex AI Generate and Upload operations
I am attempting to parallelize my content generation operations. I am generating 3 pieces of content, so I want to run a main generation process in parallel. I have a main parallel process, which calls upon 2 functions. One function generates the model content, and the other function uploads the json content to Google Cloud Storage. Both Functions and the main process is async, and I use asyncio to run all threads in parallel.
However, originally I noticed that the functions, even though they were split into different threads, would still finish in the same order:
backend-1   | INFO:main:# Atempting to Start Parallel Process
backend-1   | INFO:main:##flashcards## Starting process for flashcards
backend-1   | INFO:main:##questions## Starting process for questions
backend-1   | INFO:main:##study_outline## Starting process for study_outline
backend-1   | INFO:main:##flashcards## Thread completed in 3.88 seconds
backend-1   | INFO:main:##study_outline## Thread completed in 7.67 seconds
backend-1   | INFO:main:##questions## Thread completed in 14.78 seconds
backend-1   | INFO:main:# Ended Parallel Processing
I've been trying to dig through my code to see if there are still any syncronous processes which I have not turned asynchronous, I was wondering if someone could take a look at my code and help me asses my processes:
#Relevant Parallel setup from my API endpoint:
#prompt asset list =[], houses prompts and inputs for functions
    logger.info(f"# Atempting to Start Parallel Process")
    #Prompt info example, created with prompt engineering pipeline in prev code:
    # study_outline_info = { "fileName" : fileName , "content_type" : "study_outline" , "prompt" : full_study_outline_prompt, "filepaths": gcs_uris}
    tasks = [async_generate_model_parallel_process(prompt_info) for prompt_info in prompt_asset_list]
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
    logger.info(f"# Ended Parallel Processing")
    study_set_info = {
            "flashcards": fc_uri,
            "questions": questions_uri,
            "study_outline": study_outline_uri,
            "fileUploadRefs": fileUploadrefs
            }
    for result in results:
        if isinstance(result, dict):
            study_set_info.update(result)
        else:
            logger.error(f"Task failed with exception: {result}")

    return JSONResponse(study_set_info)

#Main Process Function:
async def async_generate_model_parallel_process(prompt_info):
start_time = time.time()
logger.debug("Entered Parallel Process")

try:
    fileName = prompt_info["fileName"]
    content_type = prompt_info["content_type"]
    prompt = prompt_info["prompt"]
    filepaths = prompt_info["filepaths"]
    logger.debug(f"Filename: {fileName}")
    logger.debug(f"content_type: {content_type}")
    logger.debug(f"filepaths: {filepaths}")
except Exception as e:
    logger.exception(f"##{content_type}## ##ERROR## Issue extracting prompt info")
    raise JSONResponse({f"##{content_type}## ##ERROR## Issue generating {content_type}": str(e)})

try:
    logger.info(f"##{content_type}## Starting process for {content_type}")
    json_string = await async_get_model_output(prompt, filepaths, content_type)
except Exception as e:
    logger.exception(f"##{content_type}## ##ERROR## Issue generating model output")
    raise JSONResponse({f"##{content_type}## ##ERROR## Issue generating {content_type}": str(e)})



try:
    
    logger.debug(f"##{content_type}## DEBUG: ATTEMPTING TO UPLOAD {content_type}")

    content_uri = await async_upload_to_storage(json_string, fileName, content_type)
    logger.debug(f"##{content_type}## DEBUG: SUCCESSFULLY UPLOADED {content_type}: {content_uri}")
    
except Exception as e:
    logger.exception(f"##{content_type}## DEBUG: Issue with Upload {content_type}")
    return JSONResponse({f"##{content_type}## DEBUG: Issue with Upload {content_type}": str(e)})

end_time = time.time()
execution_time = end_time - start_time
logger.info(f"##{content_type}## Thread completed in {execution_time:.2f} seconds")
return {content_type : content_uri}  

#Upload storage function
async def async_upload_to_storage(json_string, fileName, content_type):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('sry_study_materials')
    temp_name = f"{fileName} {content_type}"
    blob = bucket.blob(generate_unique_filename(temp_name))
    
    # Use asyncio.to_thread to run the upload in a separate thread
    await asyncio.to_thread(blob.upload_from_string, json_string)
    
    return f"gs://{bucket.name}/{blob.name}"

#Generate Content Function:
async def async_get_model_output(prompt, filepaths, content_type):
    
    vertexai.init(project=os.getenv("PROJECT_ID"), location="us-central1")
    model = GenerativeModel(model_name="gemini-1.5-flash-001")
    #Figure 
    parts = [Part.from_uri(filepath["gcs_link"], mime_type=filepath["mimetype"]) for filepath in filepaths]
    parts.append(prompt)
    # Create a GenerationConfig object with the specified parameters
    generation_config = GenerationConfig(
        temperature=0.3,
        top_p=0.3,
        max_output_tokens = 5000
        # You can add other parameters here as needed
    )
#BLOCK_ONLY_HIGH
    safety_settings = [
        SafetySetting(
        category=HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT,
        threshold=HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_ONLY_HIGH,
    ),
    SafetySetting(
        category=HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_HARASSMENT,
        threshold=HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_ONLY_HIGH,
    ),
    SafetySetting(
        category=HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_HATE_SPEECH,
        threshold=HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_ONLY_HIGH,
    ),
    SafetySetting(
        category=HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT,
        threshold=HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_ONLY_HIGH,
    ),
        # Add other categories as needed
    ]

    for attempt in range(3):
        print(f'Attempt {attempt + 1} to get model output')
        try:
            token_count = model.count_tokens(parts)
            print(f"Token count: {token_count}")

            response = await asyncio.to_thread(
                model.generate_content,
                parts,
                generation_config=generation_config,
                safety_settings=safety_settings
            )

            json_match = re.search(r'\{[\s\S]*\}', response.text)

            if json_match:
                json_string = json_match.group(0)
                try:
                    study_guide_data = json.loads(json_string)
                    print(f"##{content_type}## DEBUG CONTENT SUCCESS: Successfully Generated content and parsed JSON")
                    return json_string
                except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
                    print(f"##{content_type}##JSON decode error: {e}")
                    print(f"##{content_type}##Extracted JSON string:", json_string)
                    # Continue to next attempt
            else:
                print(f"##{content_type}## No JSON object found in the response")
        except Exception as e:
            error_message = str(e)
            truncated_message = error_message[:197] + "..." if len(error_message) > 200 else error_message
            print(f"##{content_type}## Unexpected error during attempt {attempt + 1}: {error_message}")
        
        # If we reach here, the current attempt failed. We'll continue to the next one.
        print(f"##{content_type}## Attempt {attempt + 1} failed. Moving to next attempt.")

        
        if attempt < 2:  # Don't sleep after the last attempt
            print(f"##{content_type}## Waiting 1 seconds before next attempt...")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
    # If we've exhausted all attempts without success
    raise Exception(f"##{content_type}## Failed to get valid JSON after 3 attempts")


Working through th same thing at the moment. Did you learn anything? If I multithread the execution time is near identical regardless of the max threads I configure...
